# Entity Framework - Searching by ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table called Products and a table called ProductDescription. The ProductDescription has a primary key called ProductDescriptionID. So, to get the description of a product I need to access both tables.

Here is my code to access the description of a product but I don't know how to fix it, as I'm getting: "Cannot convert lambda expression to string because it is not a delegate type".

```
        productDetailsVM.ProductDescription = db.ProductDescriptions
            .Where(c => c.ProductDescriptionID.Any(p => p.ProductID == id))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit:

```
    public partial class Product
    {    
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        etc
    }

    public partial class ProductDescription
    {
        public int ProductDescriptionID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I actually write this query?

[image][image]

Comment: Didn't you just ask the same question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699816/how-should-i-write-this-entity-framework-query

Comment: No very similar but different problems, the first one was solved. Also, different errors.

Comment: Why not just start with the Product? Assuming you have a navigation property on the product: `productDetailsVM.ProductDescription = db.Products.Single(p => p.ProductID == id).ProductDescription;`

Comment: I don't know what a navigation property is but if I try what you suggest I get "does not contain definition for ProductDescription"

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your entity models. Also, I suggest reading up on EF if you don't know what a navigation property is.

Comment: Your `ProductDescription` class has no `ProductID` property. How are you relating them together?

Comment: Class ProductDescription is partial Does this contain information about the product Id as well?

Comment: The ProductID is in Product, should it be somewhere else then?

Comment: If you want to link the description to the product then yes! How else can you join them together?

Comment: But then that would totally break as the database table has a ProductID column. Is it simply not possible to try get a product description based on the ProductDescriptionID which is in the ProductDescription table?

Comment: So do the ProductDescriptionID values equate to ProductID values?

Comment: I've added the database tables to the question

Comment: You are not answering the question: How do you link a product to a description? The tables you show us don't explain it at all.

Comment: There is no link that I can see. Either you need a ProductDescriptionID in the ProductTable or a ProductID in the ProductDescription table. How else wouldd *anyone* (or any computer) know how to match them?

Comment: There may be another table that sits in between so you have a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your database is probably new and still in the works, you have yet to defined the relationship between Product and ProductDescription (a foreign key of ProductID in the ProductDescription table).

Once you have that relationship set up and have refreshed your EF diagram (assuming your not using Code First) you will be able to do:

```cs
 var productDescription = db.Product.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ProductID == id).ProductDescription;
```

This assumes that a Product has only 1 ProductDescription.

Comment: This is what I was going to answer, In terms of terminology OP needs a navigation property between his two entities

Answer (score 0):

Wont this do it?

```
 productDetailsVM.ProductDescription = db.ProductDescriptions
            .Where(c => c.ProductID == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: "Does not contain definition for "ProductID""

Comment: Hmm... can you post the entity models? Your attempt has the PD having a ProductID...

Comment: I've added the database tables to the question

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want a product to have a single description you either have to  add the `ProductId` field to `ProductDescription` table or the `ProductDescriptionID` field to the `Product` table.
This is called Entity splitting, you can find a video of this approach [here.](https://youtu.be/B5BQo-5xdxE?list=PL6n9fhu94yhUPBSX-E2aJCnCR3-_6zBZx)

Supposing that you want a product to have multiple descriptions and description multiple products (many to many) you need a "Bridge Table" with just two fields (product and description ids) conforming the primary key of this bridge table, this way you will have in your model a (many to many) relation, again there is a detailed video [here.](https://youtu.be/uMQwORSTGX4?list=PL6n9fhu94yhUPBSX-E2aJCnCR3-_6zBZx).